# html5 error : Element head is missing a required instance of child element title

Tags: html

I'm trying to send an email but the email provider doesn't let me send it if the body is not well formatted html provider. Can anyone help me to validate this?

The error is `Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div style="background-color: rgb(238,238,238);padding: 0;margin: 0;font-family: Open Sans , Helvetica Neue , Helvetica , Arial , sans-serif;font-size: 13.0px;background-color: rgb(238,238,238);">
</div>
</html>
```

VALIDATOR: http://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 4):

Your document is valid HTML5. The validator incorrectly issues an error message. Its diagnostics is self-contradictory, because it reports the lack of a `title` element as an error, yet quotes the HTML 5.1 draft as saying, among other things, that a the element is not required when “title information is available from a higher-level protocol”. The rule is clarified in the HTML5 spec as follows, at the end of the description of the [`head` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element):

> **Note.** The title element is a required child in most situations, but when a higher-level protocol provides title information, e.g. in
>   the Subject line of an e-mail when HTML is used as an e-mail authoring
>   format, the title element can be omitted.

There is currently no way telling the validator that a document being checked is to be used as the body of an e-mail message (and no way for a validator to actually check that!). I have submitted a [bug report](https://bugzilla.validator.nu/show_bug.cgi?id=1017) that suggests making this a warning, not an error, but I don’t expect this to be implemented anytime soon.

So you can tell your email provider that this error message is incorrect and cite the W3C HTML5 Recommendation on this. However, if they actually require a clean validator report rather than validity, you hardly have any other option than add a `title` element. Any nonempty content there will do, as far as the validator is concerned, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Message</title>
<div style="background-color: rgb(238,238,238);padding: 0;margin: 0;font-family: Open Sans , Helvetica Neue , Helvetica , Arial , sans-serif;font-size: 13.0px;background-color: rgb(238,238,238);">
</div>
</html>
```

(As an aside, the `<html>` and `</html>` tags are not required.)

You might also consider modifying your e-mail message generation software so that in inserts a copy of the e-mail message header (placed in the `Subject:` header) into the `title` element. In that case, remember to escape any `&` in the content by `&amp;` any `<` in the content by `&lt;`.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the body-tag and the head-tag. And it should contain a title, which is not empty and also a charset setting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(238,238,238);padding: 0;margin: 0;font-family: Open Sans , Helvetica Neue , Helvetica , Arial , sans-serif;font-size: 13.0px;background-color: rgb(238,238,238);">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As told in the validator:

> Content model for element head:
>   If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of metadata content, of which no more than one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.
>   Otherwise: One or more elements of metadata content, of which exactly one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.

Comment: I get the same error though the line number is different. Check with http://validator.w3.org/check